SQL Server | Target Memory vs Total Memory
A minha questão é a seguinte, existem dois indicadores na DMV sys.dm_os_performance_counters que tenho de fazer análise a Target Server Memory (KB)
e o Total Server Memory (KB):
Target Server Memory(KB):
O que eu entendo é que esta representa a quantidade ideal de memória que o SQL Server gostaria de ter para a carga de trabalho atual.
Total Server Memory(KB):
O que eu entendo é que esta representa a quantidade de memória efetivamente alocada pelo SQL Server no momento.
Ou seja se o Total <  Target isto significa que existe uma pressão de memória, precisa de mais memoria para ter uma performance maior na instancia.
Se o Total > Target então deduzo que tem memoria suficiente  para o que está a pedir e  esta a trabalhar em pleno.
Isto é correto?

Foi isto que você leu? https://deltabravo.ai/delta-bravo-performance-counters-sql-server-target-vs-total-memory/

Já li vários artigos mas nada que me indique se é assim tão linear

Boas-vindas Ruben. Segue a documentação oficial: Isolate memory used by SQL Server (o link está em inglês porque as vezes a tradução não soa exatamente como deveria ter, quando é necessário alguma adaptação idioma).
